# expect code in bash script in using SCP

Tags: bash, expect

I have tried to write a script to download file from remote server as below:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 ######!/usr/bin/expect -f

 # connect via scp

 server='remoteserver@202.132.251.225'
 pass='abcde12345'
 remoteServerDesitination='/home/vijay/myHOMEdir'
 file_to_get='amber9_installation_steps.txt'
 directory_to_safe='/home/vijay/Simulation-Folders'

 /usr/bin/expect  << EOF 

 spawn scp "$server:$remoteServerDesitination/$file_to_get"    $directory_to_safe

 expect {

 -re ".*sword.*" {
 exp_send "$pass\n"
 }
 }

 interact

 EOF
```

when I execute this script, it doesn't pop out any error and no files downlaoded either. I can not trace out what the missing error.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812232/error-handling-in-bash-expect-script for some ideas. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is your expect script attempting to supply a password to `scp`?  You may be better off using a keypair, and just skipping password authentication altogether.  Try googling "ssh keypair tutorial" for instructions on setting this up.

Comment: yea.. I want to supply the password to the scp together rather then prompting for password. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sshpass`!

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER=remoteserver@202.132.251.225
PASS=abcde12345
REMOTESERVERDESITINATION=/home/vijay/myHOMEdir
FILE_TO_GET=amber9_installation_steps.txt
DIRECTORY_TO_SAFE=/home/vijay/Simulation-Folders
sshpass -p $PASS scp $SERVER:$REMOTESERVERDESITINATION/$FILE_TO_GET $DIRECTORY_TO_SAFE
```